# How do you move rust snafu error enum into a module and use it from another module?

Tags: rust

I'm breaking up a huge file into modules, things worked before I broke it up, now the Snafu error handling won't compile.

util.rs:

```
#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
pub enum Error {
    #[snafu(display("The start time {:#?} is invalid: {:#?}", start, source))]
    StartTimeInvalid {
        start: SystemTime,
        source: SystemTimeError,
        backtrace: Backtrace,
    },
    #[snafu(display("error: {}", desc))]
    Any { desc: String },
}

pub trait Elapsed {
    fn elapsed(&self) -> Result<u128, Error>;
}
```

timer.rs:

```
pub struct Timer {
    start: SystemTime,
}

impl Timer {
    pub fn new() -> Self { Self { start: SystemTime::now() } }
}
impl Elapsed for Timer {
    fn elapsed(&self) -> Result<u128, Error> {
        let start = self.start;
        Ok(start.elapsed().context( Error::StartTimeInvalid{ start })?.as_nanos())
    }
}
```

I get two compiler errors for context() are:

- missing `backtrace`, `source`
- the trait `snafu::IntoError<_>` is not implemented for `util::util::Error`

I suspect I'm needing to import something else, but no idea what it may be.

Answer (score 1):

solved.

```
#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
#[snafu(visibility = "pub")]
pub enum Error {
```

then add this in module that uses it

```
use crate::util::StartTimeInvalid;
```